How tf.cast makes a matrix?
Let me ask (possibly) a very basic question.
See the code below.
import tensorflow as tf

i = tf.range(3)[:, tf.newaxis]
j = tf.range(3)
tf.cast(i>=j, dtype="int32")

When I run this code, I get the below.
I mean a lower triangular 3x3 matrix(tensor).
<tf.Tensor: shape=(3, 3), dtype=int32, numpy=
array([[1, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 0],
       [1, 1, 1]], dtype=int32)>

What I want to know is

How tf.newaxis works in i = tf.range(3)[:, tf.newaxis]
As far as I understand, i is basicly a column vector but to make it a matrix, it makes a room for more columns.
Is this right?

In the code above, I didn't make a 3x3 matrix anywhere but finally I get a 3x3 matrix.
tf.cast is originally a function to convert a type from one to another, not a function to make a matrix.
But actually I get a matrix.
Why?



Hi @hopstepforward , We use tf.newaxis to increase the dimension of tensor,In your code i = tf.range(3)[:, tf.newaxis] your range(3) create a 1D tensor of shape (3,): [0, 1, 2] and [:, tf.newaxis] help to convert 1D into 2D tensor by adding a new axis
Second Issue :-In tensorflow , Broadcasting allows operations between tensors of different shapes in your case,i = tf.range(3)[:, tf.newaxis]is a column vector and j = tf.range(3) is a row vector) ,Broadcasting automatically expanding them to form a matrix.
